# How to get the index of some element in select query without fetching all the data

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let we have some select statement:

```
select id, data from mytable order by data;
```

Is it possible to get the index of the row with given `id` in so ordered data set, without fetching all rows up to the `id` and counting?

I am working with sqlite3 and answers for sqlite dialect of SQL are better, but the answers about general ANSI SQL are ok as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can use an aggregation query:

```
select count(*)
from mytable t
where t.data <= (select data from mytable where id = $id);
```

Note:  This assumes that `data` is unique.  If there are duplicates, then you might want the equivalent of a `rank` instead.  This look like:

```
select 1 + count(*)
from mytable t
where t.data < (select data from mytable where id = $id);
```

Comment: The second query is a little bit unclear. The constant 1 can be wrong if there are more than one elements with data == data(id=$id).

Comment: @johnfound . . . The second query is equivalent to the `rank()` function in ANSI SQL.  It is probably the *most* appropriate ways to handle ties.

Comment: Yes, it is. But rank() is not a solution to my problem. Anyway, I found the proper solution, using your answer, so will check it as an answer.